# If condition inside Concrete5 Job not working

Tags: jobs, concrete5

I don't even have a clue why this is happening. The if condition in my job is not working properly. I triple checked the $flag variable and it is true. Still the code always goes to the else condition.

```
$flag = file_exists($csvFile);
if($flag){
     //A big chunk of code
} else {
     return 'Whatever you do I will always go here XD';
}
```

I hard coded true inside if, it works properly. Then another if inside that chunk of code also always goes to else. Again double checked Express. Express object exists and object is returned properly. And is_object returns true.

```
$flag = file_exists($csvFile);
if(true){
     //Some code here
     $entity = Express::getObjectByHandle('user');
     if(is_object($entity)){ 
          // Another chunk of code
     } else {
          return 'You cant escape from me that easily... XD';
     }
     //some code here
} else {
     return "Now I'm a good boy";
}
```

---

Tried a bunch of things. The code works without any problems in single page controllers. What ever I do it's just **not working**. I'm running **PHP 5.6.10** on MAMP. Conceret5 **8.1.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Looks like I found the fix. It looks like a simple matter but don't know for sure. I was running the job from dashboard, I didn't knew I could run the same job from the url as well (Automate job option URL). It worked fine when I ran it from URL and Magically it started working inside the Dashboard as well. I will look into it in detail when I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen something like this is with a buggy older version of PHP.

You could try moving some code around like so:

```
if($flag = file_exists($csvFile)) {
  // code to handle file
} else {
  // no file
}
```

A followup post would help...

Comment: Tried that as well. No luck.